# ANOVA test mean against predefined constant

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, p-value

***How can I calculate the p-value (statistical significance) if my hypothesis asks for specific mean values?***

I suppose this can be somehow calculated using ANOVA, but I could only find examples where the hypothesis states that all means are the same.

I.e. I have four groups, and my hypothesis states that the means will be:

```
x1=1
x2=2
x3=3
x4=4
```

---

***Example:***

Suppose the following (simplified) example:

I collect data by asking people on the street to order fruits according to their preference. There are four fruits (groups) to order: `apple`, `banana`, `coconut`, `pear`

So if participant `P1` likes apples `A` the most, followed by coconut `C`, then pear `P` and bananas `B` as least preferred, I note the following data (position in the ordered list):

```
P1: A=1, B=4, C=2, P=3
```

participant `P2` likes Pears the most, then apples, then coconut and at least bananas:

```
P2: A=2, B=4, C=3, P=1
```

and so on. This yields a table:

```
    A    |    B    |    C    |    P
----------------------------------------
    1    |    4    |    2    |    3
    2    |    4    |    3    |    1
... and a lot more data
```

My hypothesis is, that apple will be the most liked fruit, followed by banana, then coconut and as least preferred pears. This can be stated, using means, as:

```
xA = 1
xB = 2
xC = 3
xP = 4
```

How can I now check if the hypothesis is confirmed and with which statistical significance (e.g. is p-value smaller than 0.05?)

Answer (score 0):

Posted the same question here:
http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/61492-Hypothesis-testing-with-predefined-constant-means?p=176916&viewfull=1#post176916

The proposed solution was:

> If I understand you question correctly, you do not need to specify the
>   means to get an answer , You could just run a Kruskal-Wallis test and
>   the appropriate post-hoc test afterwards (e.g Dunn's test).
>
> There are many more possibilities for the outcome then your
>   specification of means would allow: e.g if the Kruskal-Wallis is not
>   significant therenate no clear prefemceres in any direction, or you
>   could get a clear preferenc for the first position but none for the
>   others and so on.

This seems to do it!